# How do I start a process with a nice value of -20 and not give it root privilege?

Tags: process, priority, nice

I would like to start a process with a nice value of -20. This requires me to use a command like

```
sudo nice -n -20 matlab
```

However, this starts matlab as root too. Is there a way to have matlab as non-root?

My current approach is

```
sudo nice -n -20 sudo -u myusername matlab
```

which to me looks like a hack. Is there a direct approach to do this?

Comment: You should be able to just drop the `sudo`. `root` is not needed to nice your own process.

Comment: If you want to set a higher priority than the default, you do need superuser.  (-20 is the highest priority.)  The only other way I can think of to do this would be to sudo renice after it is started. However, since you're running matlab interactively, that's easier said than done.

Comment: Not a hack, that's the way to go.

Comment: @jordanm - Without a sudo, this is the right command - `nice -n -20 matlab` and this is the output nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied. Matlab starts up and the nice value is 0.

Comment: @AlanShutko - I could run `system('sudo renice ...')` in MATLAB, but matlab starts 2 processes - MATLAB and matlab_helper. I might have to do it on both. moreover I also want all my MATLAB processes to be of high priority - when I start `matlabpool local ` for parallel processing.

@HaukeLaging - I am beginning to think you are right.

Comment: Some things can be done too, with super user `htop` access to.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would start it normally and use "renice" afterwards...

However I was able to make a quick hack together with "su" which works:

```
sudo nice -n -20 su -c command_to_run user_to_run_as
```

If you don't have to give sudo a password - perhaps because you've already just given it - you may add an `&` to put the whole thing in the background.

Since you already become root with the sudo-command, `su` won't ask you for a password. I was able to start a X-program from a terminal-emulator under X.  If you want to run the X-program as another user than the user owning the X-session, you'll probably need to explicitly tell X to allow it (open for X-clients from that user).

Comment: Thank you. So I think the way I figured was the only way to do about.

Comment: This works! The only thing I am encountering now is that I have no standard output. How to solve this? E.g. `sudo nice -n 19 su -c $(echo "test")` gives no output.

Comment: My bad, you need to do `sudo nice -n 19 su -c "echo 'test'"'
When you want to run a function in `su -c do`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3727572/2522849

Answer (score 15):

I have found this could be done by modifying the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` (at least on some linux distros). In my case, I simply added:

```
#<domain>    <type>  <item>  <value>
my_user        -     nice       -20`
```

then you can execute

`nice -n -20 matlab`

Logout and back in after saving changes to `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/do-changes-in-etc-security-limits-conf-require-a-reboot) explains why.

Comment: After making this change, should log out/in again: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108603/247665

Answer (score 12):

One step further @Jordan: Here's the elegant solution against `sudo nice -n -xx su <username> -c matlab` hack.

> Note: Using username=`sid`, matlab meta-data dir=`/var/lib/matlab`, nice=`-10` -- change at your will

1. Create matlab meta-data dir

   ```
   sudo mkdir /var/lib/matlab
   ```
2. Add specified user to launch matlab & right permission

   ```
   sudo useradd -d /var/lib/matlab sid
   sudo chown sid:sid /var/lib/matlab
   ```
3. Set user password

   ```
   sudo passwd sid
   ```
4. Append following to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

   ```
   sid - priority -10
   ```
5. Setup & copy ssh-key to automate login (optional)

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa #following key passwd misc   
   ssh-copy-id sid@localhost #using sid's passwd
   ```
6. Create matlab shell wrapper (fix [silent fail error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183977/110137))

   ```
   sudo -i
   cat &lt;&lt;EOF &gt;&gt;/usr/local/bin/wmatlab
   #!/bin/bash --
   # A wrapper to launch matlab
   /usr/local/MATLAB/&lt;version&gt;/bin/matlab -desktop
   EOF
   chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wmatlab
   ```
7. Adjust "sid"'s login shell

   ```
   sudo usermod -s /usr/local/bin/wmatlab sid
   ```
8. Start matlab using `ssh` with `Xforward`

   ```
   ssh -X sid@localhost
   ```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

pam allows you to set limits on nice per group its configuration file:

> @grnice   hard priority -20
>
> @grnice   hard nice     -20

And make sure the group the process runs in grnice.

Answer (score 1):

As @jordanm said drop sudo.  You can nice your own processes to give them a lower priority:

```
nice -20 matlab
```

No `sudo`.

Comment: This did not work. `system('ps a -o pid -o comm -o nice')` got me 
`13580 MATLAB           19` - MATLAB is running with the lowest priority instead of the highest. My question was on how to increase the priority and not reduce it.

Comment: Without a `sudo`, this is the right command - `nice -n -20 matlab` and this is the output `nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied`. Matlab starts up and the nice value is 0.

Comment: OP wants not *increase* priority (negative nice), ie. "nice --20 mathlab" (double -) in the old notation, "nice -n -20 mathlab" in the new.  Only root may use negative nice-values.

Comment: CAP_SYS_NICE would also allow the OP to do this without root privileges, but involves delving into Linux capabilities (something not a lot of people understand and might be more work than it's worth). I just mention it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635515/how-to-set-cap-sys-nice-capability-to-a-linux-user

Comment: @LordLoh I'm assuming you're responding to me. That post isn't saying the CAP_SYS_NICE doesn't work or whatever you're thinking, it's talking about a process that's dropped a capability never being able to re-attain it, which is very true. It's still possible to give a non-root user CAP_SYS_NICE and then that account can renice PID's to the heart's content (assuming it never gives it up) without being given root permissions.

Comment: I just put the link of the closest post I found on the topic as a reference for anyone who might come across this thread :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add the user to sudoers (actually, a new file in /etc/sudoers.d, but its the same premise):

```
niceuser ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/nice
```

Then, as the "niceuser":

```
niceuser@localhost $ sudo nice -n -10 command...
```

and it does what I need (that is, my user can now increase the priority of {command ...}).  It supports multiple users, etc. - use `man 5 sudoers` for details.

Comment: That still runs command as root, which is what the poster is trying to avoid.

Comment: I agree with @KyleButt - we should run the command under the same user and from the same directory, etc, same environment, etc, rather then under root which will require "setuser" or whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option (simple, but less secure) is to enable setuid/setgid permission for `nice` executable.

```
sudo chmod +s /usr/bin/nice
```

setuid assign any user who can execute the file the effective UID of the file owner's (in this case `root`) when executing the file, thus is equivalent as running as that user. setguid does the same for effective GID.

---

Or you can do it more securely:

```
# create a system group named `nice'
groupadd -r nice

# set the owner group for `nice' executable
chgrp nice /usr/bin/nice

# disallow other users to run `nice`
chmod o-x /usr/bin/nice

# allow anyone who are able to execute the file gain a setuid as root
chmod u+s /usr/bin/nice

# add your user to the group
usermod -a -G nice <your-user-name>
```

Beware you need to re-login your account for new group to take effect.