# Unable to change ulimit setting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit

I edited `/etc/security/limits.conf` to have

```
root hard nofile 20000
root soft nofile 10000
```

And added

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

to `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`.

After reboot and relogin `ulimit -n` still shows 1024.

If I do `su` and try `ulimit -n` again then it shows 10000. But after a relogin it goes back to 1024.

Comment: you don't necessarily have to reboot after changing `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/do-changes-in-etc-security-limits-conf-require-a-reboot

Also, I think http://serverfault.com/questions/356962/where-are-the-default-ulimit-values-set-linux-centos might answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the manual: [`man limits.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)

That will show you that the first field in that configuration file is the `<domain>` or simplified: the users or groups for whom the setting is applied to. So when you use `root` there it's completely expected that it only works for `root` and not for any other user.

Try the following to apply it to all users or better find some middle ground and apply to the correct users/groups.

```
*     hard      nofile     20000
```

Comment: Hey there, my goal was to increase it for the root user, I login as root and ulimit -n shows 1024, if I do `su` and then ulimit -n it shows 10000.

Answer (score 1):

For RHEL and related distributions, there is now a new directory /etc/security/limits.d

The files within this directory silently override the information in the /etc/security/limits.conf file(!).

Check for 90-nproc.conf and you'll see the culprit there.

You can create new files in this directory - they are read in numeric order, so for application specific values create a file named something like 95-appname.conf and put the values required in there.

Note that any new files must have the extension '.conf' or the system will ignore them.