# Changes to /etc/security/limits.conf and /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf have no effect

Tags: centos, ulimit

On a CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Linux kernel version 3.10.x) VM, I added the following lines to both /etc/security/limits.conf and /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf:

```
someuser          soft    nofile     8000
someuser          hard    nofile     8000
```

After rebooting the VM, `ulimit -n` still reports 4096, and `ulimit -n 8000` still results in "-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted".

I'm stumped as to how to increase the open files limit at this point.

Comment: How are you logging in?

Comment: Logging in via SSH -- this is an Openstack VM running in a private cloud -- as user someuser.  Editing the two mentioned config files using sudo.

Comment: Are you using passwords or SSH keys?

Comment: SSH key (PEM file)

Comment: Cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108603/59808

Comment: I just burned several hours tracing something similar. The answer was revealed by running `strace` on the process, as suggested by the fine folks at https://serverfault.com/questions/569288/ulimit-n-not-changing-values-limits-conf-has-no-effect

Answer (score 9):

The error might occurs due to many reasons.

First of all, Use the following command command to display maximum number of open file descriptors:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

Let's pretend the output was 4096, what does it mean? It means, 4096 files a normal user can have open in single login session, you can also display it by checking its Hard and Soft limits by using the commands as follows:

```
$ ulimit -Hn
$ ulimit -Sn
```

The number of concurrently open file descriptors throughout the system can be changed by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`. You can increase the maximum number of open files by setting system-wide file descriptors limits as a new value in kernel variable in `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` as follows:

```
$ sysctl -w fs.file-max=200000     #it forces the limit to 200000 files
```

Then you should edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` file so that after reboot the setting will remain as you wished. To do so, add the following lines:

```
$ fs.file-max = 200000
```

No need to log out and log back in again, just type:

```
$ sysctl -p
```

Then you can verify changes by:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max

OR

$ sysctl fs.file-max
```

Then for changing Soft and Hard limits for users, it's better to login as root since a normal user can only change its Soft limit, Hard limits are managed by root. As You've mentioned, for doing it as root you should change User Level File-Discriptor (FD) in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. For instance if it's for Oracle user:

```
oracle           soft    nofile          4096
oracle           hard    nofile          63536
```

For seeing the changes, you do not need to reboot, just reloging via `sudo -i` and check if it works or not, so you can make sure what the problem is.
And for users without login, you should do the following as root:

```
$ sudo -i -u <user>
```

BTW, you may be in need of editing /etc/pam.d/login file and add the following line:

```
$ session required pam_limits.so
```

`pam_limit.so` in /etc/pam.d/login means at login time but no on sudo while `/etc/pam.d/sudo` limits will also be applied when running sudo without "-i", you may also need apply the above changes in /etc/pam.d/system-auth depending on your needs. I recommend you read about PAM modules.

BTW, for instant applying limits to currently running processes you should do the following additionally to changing `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
$ prlimit
```

I recommend you read this [article from RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Shell_Limits_for_the_Oracle_User.html), since you may face with:

> On some Linux systems setting "hard" and "soft" limits in the
>   following examples might not work properly when you log in as user
>   oracle via SSH. It might work if you log in as root and su to oracle.
>   If you have this problem try to set UsePrivilegeSeparation to "no" in
>   /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart the SSH daemon by executing service
>   sshd restart. The privilege separation does not work properly with PAM
>   on some Linux systems. Make sure to talk to the people in charge of
>   security before disabling the SSH security feature "Privilege
>   Separation".

I hope I could help. Good luck.

Comment: Here's what I have right now:  

    $ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max  
    **100000**  
  
    $ grep "fs.file-max" /etc/sysctl.conf  
    fs.file-max = **100000**  
  
    $ /opt/diagnostics/PerfTest/ ulimit -n  
    **4096**  
  
--Sam

Comment: Also added `session required pam_limits.so` to /etc/pam.d/login, logged out and back in, no change.

Comment: @SaminMA You should change your `ulimit` yourself, I just said how you should increase your fs.file-max so it will allow you to change your hard limit.

Comment: I can not change the ulimit for files (nofile) -- that's the entire point of my question.  Despite having edited the 2 files mentioned in the title, and now also /etc/sysctl.conf and /etc/pam.d/login, per your suggestions, I still can not change the ulimit for files.

Comment: Modifying `/etc/pam.d/login` should be unnecessary, because `login` includes the common file `system-auth` (as do many other files in `/etc/pam.d`), and the latter actually requires `pam_limits.so`.

Answer (score 3):

You may need check profile of someuser. When someuser login. profile can change its ulimit. 
Files to be check:
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
~someuser/.bash_profile
~someuser/.bashrc

Comment: I was going crazy for hours trying to figure it out. Your answer was spot on. Thanks