# Program won't load through KDE icon

Tags: icons, kde4

So I can load the program through the terminal by running the application as

```
sh /path/to/folder/bin/program
```

but when I'm trying to make a selectable icon through KDE Menu Editor I get the splash icon for the program but it doesn't load.  I can't figure out why this is happening.

I even tried writing a script that runs the program and having KDE Menu Editor point to this script instead as

```
/path/to/script
```

and that doesn't work either.  I'm extremely lost.  I just get the splash screen and the bouncing icon, and then it hangs.

Why will it run fine through the terminal and not through kde?

**FIXED**
Program was MATLAB and the solution was to use an environment

> env -u _JAVA_OPTIONS /home/steven/MATLAB/bin/matlab -desktop -nosplash

Comment: Can you check using `ps` if your program is indeed launched or not?

Comment: ps shows it when I launch through the terminal, but not through kde.  Same with top.

Comment: Can you check if your application shows up in [ksystemlog](https://www.kde.org/applications/system/ksystemlog/) ?

Comment: Besides that that crashes (don't feel like bothering with fixing it), would this show anything different than ps and top mid launching?  I can't see it in ps or top even while the splash screen is showing.

Comment: What program are you trying to run?

Comment: It was MATLAB.  I forgot that I solved this.  Thanks for reminding me.  I'll mark it as solved

Comment: Nice one. Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use the environment option

> env -u _JAVA_OPTIONS /home/steven/MATLAB/bin/matlab -desktop -nosplash